# Calculating difference in column value from one row to the next

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using an Access DB to keep track of Utility Usage on hundreds of accounts.  The meters in these accounts have consumption values only per month.  I need to take the consumption value of this month and subtract it from the value of the previous month. to get the consumption for this month.  I know that in SQL Server, there is a lead/lag function that can calculate those differences.  Is there a similar function in access? or is there a simple way to subtract the value in one row from the one above it?

Ex.

```
The first Line is Billed Date
The Second Line is the Meter Reading
The Third Line is Consumption

1/26/2014
2/25/2014
3/27/2014
4/28/2014
5/26/2014
7/29/2014

0
3163
4567
5672
7065
8468

1538
1625
1404
1105
1393
1403
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not quite get some of your results, but I think you want something like:

```
SELECT Meters.MeterDate, 
     Meters.MeterReading, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 MeterReading 
     FROM Meters m WHERE m.MeterDate <Meters.MeterDate 
     ORDER BY MeterDate DESC) AS LastReading, 
     [MeterReading]-Nz([LastReading],0) AS MonthResult
FROM Meters
ORDER BY Meters.MeterReading;
```

[image]